# VS Code imposing undesired XML formatting (e.g. white space added to closing tag)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code and 0pening another's project and vs wants to reformate the tags and make 1k+ modifications.

Original tags lack the extra whitespace that VS Code imposes.

Original tag:
`<regexCodeList/>`

VS Code changes to:
`<regexCodeList />`

e.g. adding a space. Anyone know of a way to turn off this behavior? Yes, I know it may be preferable, but doesn't help if that isn't the project's standard.